# Update database without editing previous entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, database

I'm updating data in an (SQL) database every time I submit my form after 1 entry, for example, element_1 is entered and submitted now, element_2 will be entered and submitted 20 or 30 minutes later

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="element_1" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="element_2" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="element_3" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="element_4" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="element_5" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="timeStamp_1" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="timeStamp_2" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="timeStamp_3" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="timeStamp_4" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="timeStamp_5" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

the result of my form should look like this after everything is submitted

```
{
    "element": ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    "timeStamp": ['time_1','time_2','time_3','time_4','time_4']
}
```

My problem now lays in the timeStamp, since I'm getting it with `Date()` with Javascript, **every time someone submits element_1, timeStamp_1 must be submitted with** and so on.

How do save timeStamps without replacing the previous one(s) with current one on each submits?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What database do you use? How do you send the data to the server? Timestamp is really in the form 'time_X'?

Comment: It similar to versioning of records - you want to preserve timestamp to be able history of changes. So, save new row for each time when you edit the records. I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @slesh every time someone submits element_1, timeStamp_1 must be submitted with and so on

Comment: Then map items with respective timestamps using plain js object.

var itemTimestampMap = Object.create(null);
itemTimestampMap[item1.name] = new Date();
itemTimestampMap[item2.name] = new Date();
...
itemTimestampMap[itemN.name] = new Date();

function submit() {
   var item = ....;
   sendPost({
      data: item,
      timestamp: itemTimestampMap[item.name]
   })
}

Comment: I agree, that it is not clearly what do you need...

Answer (score 0):

Then map items with respective timestamps using plain js object.

```
var itemTimestampMap = Object.create(null);
itemTimestampMap[item1.name] = new Date();
itemTimestampMap[item2.name] = new Date();
...
itemTimestampMap[itemN.name] = new Date();

function submit() {
   var item = ....;
   sendPost({
      data: item,
      timestamp: itemTimestampMap[item.name]
   })
}
```

Comment: do I need to declare all the itemN ?

Comment: As a way, but you can map them by id also. It is variety and depends on you issue specific

Answer (score -1):

If you use mongodb.Mongodb has update method.You can update the particular documnet.Please check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

In case of sql [sql update here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)